# git log to show tag with commit id

Tags: git, ubuntu

Run git on mac and linux, I got different result.

On mac, I run `git log`, it shows commit id and tag (if it has)

```
commit d7320183a41a7595d8d8288dfe10289aaa045363 (tag: 2.0.6)
```

But in linux, only shows commit id

```
commit d7320183a41a7595d8d8288dfe10289aaa045363
```

Are there any setting I need to do to get tag list with commit, it will be convenience.

Comment: set `log.decorate` to `true` (the old default of `false` switched to `true` in Git 2.13.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew the reason.

In ubuntu, git stays with old version (v2.7.1) even I run `apt-get install git`, after upgrade it ([How do I install the latest version of Git with apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-git-with-apt)) , the latest version is 2.19.1, it shows the tag with commit id now.